# Request with initiator=localhost gets intercepted by DeclarativeNetRequest even though the rule says otherwise

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-redirect

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 2,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": { "regexSubstitution": "http://localhost:28438/check-url?url=\\0" }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "^(https?\\://)?[^\\:]+$",
      "resourceTypes": [ "main_frame" ],
      "excludedDomains":["localhost"]
      
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {        
        "regexSubstitution": "\\1"
      }
    },
    "condition": {
"regexFilter": "^(?:http\\://)?localhost.+pass\\?url=(.+)$",
      "resourceTypes": [ "main_frame" ]      
    }
  }
]
```

According to the above rule #1, every request originating from localhost should be ignored and the rest should be redirected to the local server.
I have added the rule #2 for a possibly broader view of the case; it's really redundant to post it here.

My expectation, however, is not satisfied and the request gets intercepted, resulting in an infinite loop:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd1pa.png]

In this case, I try to open the msn website and it gets intercepted by the first rule (the second rule acts OK).

Comment: The screenshot shows that everything works per your rules: 1) check-url redirect, 2) pass redirect, 3) original URL redirect, 4) the first rule matches this original URL and the loop goes again and again. You can add some parameter to the URL in step 3 and detect it in step 1. You can also open a feature request on https://crbug.com to add a flag to rules that somehow prevents the loop.

Comment: @wOxxOm I see what you mean, however I have considered that problem which is why I added  "excludedDomains":["localhost"] to the first rule. 
I have also thought of that alternative approach you suggested, however I am trying to get it sorted using a possibly "officially supported" approach.

Comment: In your screenshot the loop in step 4 is caused by `www.msn.com` which is not excluded.

Comment: From the docs:"excludedDomains: This matches against the request initiator and not the request url."
I have excluded the initiator localhost, have I not?

Comment: Looks like the API doesn't think so in this case. It might be a bug or an inherent feature/limitation?

Comment: I discovered that all requests originating from a 307 redirect do not observe the excludedDomains rule. So it's not just about localhost. 
Any thoughts? 
P.S I posted an issue over at crbug.com.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? Having the same issue

Comment: @tob88
https://crbug.com/1167127